# GitHub client as a Progressive Web App: how to deal with commits and pushes?

Tags: git, github, version-control, push, progressive-web-apps

I am asking this question since I want to wrap my head around how to deal with this kind of issue and seek advice from the community. For anyone who doesn't know, a PWA can work while offline and uses ServiceWorkers to handle requests and do background synchronisation (and several other stuff).

I want to build a PWA that is meant to be a GitHub client and in its features, I want to implement making commits and pushes to a repository. From my perspective, making a commit is straight-forward and doesn't cause any problem since there is no change to a remote.

However, when a push is made there may be some issues. The user may be online and the push is made straight away. If he isn't online, the ServiceWorker will keep it in the background and when there is connectivity, the push shall be made.

And what if some other user has made a push while the current user was offline? The Git version control should handle the situation? Is my thinking flawed anywhere? Is it feasible to avoid issues on the remote by using the SW?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not flaw for git. But a situation for all the remote repos which located different from the local machine.

Users in a local repo shouldn’t always offline (they need to co-work with others and make contributions to the remote repo). When the offline users are online, they should pull and push to remote repo (update local repo and contributor to remote repo).

Detail steps for this situation as below:

Assume the commit history on master branch original as below:

```
…---A---B---C master, origin/master
```

And a user who works offline commit local changes (commit `D` and commit `E`), then the local commit history as below:

```
…---A---B---C---D---E master
            |
       origin/master
```

While another user push changes commit `F` and commit `G` to remote repo.

Now if the offline user is online, if he/she push changes directly to remote remote, git will reject to push since remote repo has new changes which the local repo doesn’t have, and hint to use `git pull` firstly.

And there usually has two ways to pull the changes from remote:

1. **Pull with default manner**

   After executing `git pull origin master`, the commit history will be:

   ```
   …---A---B---C---D---E---M  master
                \         /
                 F-------G   origin/master
   ```

   It merge `origin/master` into the local `master`, and the commit `M` is the merge commit.
2. **Pull with rebase**

   After executing the command `git pull origin master --rebase`, it will rebase the local changes on the top of the `origin/master`. The commit history will be:

   ```
   …---A---B---C---F---G---D'---E' master
                       |
                  origin/master
   ```

So even a user is offline, he can only work on the local repo. When the user online again, he/she can work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to keep a peace of mind and knowing that what I'm trying to achieve is doable. From this point on, maybe I will only allow the user to push if he is online and the repository is updated. If not, pull first and then push.

Comment: Yeah, this is the mechanism git follows. When a user is offline, he can not push to remote; When there has new changes (which not exist in local repo) before `git push`, git automatically stop to push and hint pull first.